# Wago PLC - assign IP address/factory reset

Tags: ethernet, dhcp, ip-address

I have a Wago 750-352 Ethernet Coupler which I believe has been assigned an IP address already.

In attempting to use the Wago BootP Server to connect to the device I am unable to connect to it.  I believe this is because the device already has a static IP and therefore will not listen over BootP.  I have triple checked MAC address in the config file, etc.

Is it possible to perform a factory reset such that I can erase the existing IP address in the EEPROM and connect via BootP without the Wago "communication Cable 750-923"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wago BootP Server should have been able to assign/reassign the device's address.  The coupler had some kind of internal short or fault that I was unaware of at the time, so this was a super unusual instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation. You may need special, proprietary cables for this.

[WAGO-I/O-SYSTEM 750
ETHERNET Fieldbus Coupler
750-352
10/100 Mbit/s; digital and analog Signals](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjskpycsebLAhXIlYMKHWXXCa8QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wago.com%2Fwagoweb%2Fdocumentation%2F750%2Feng_manu%2Fcoupler_controller%2Fm07500352_00000000_0en.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGZZTZ5oz0VPIB8gurUt0Dutr3Q0A&sig2=mE_dTSNrJjExGdCcefMSpg&cad=rja)

> **8.2.3 Assigning IP Address via WAGO-ETHERNET-Settings**
>
> This program is used to configure an IP address via serial
>   communications interface, to reset the fieldbus coupler parameters to
>   the factory settings and to delete and extract the Flash File System
>   in which the HTML pages of the fieldbus coupler are stored.
>
> WAGO communication cables or WAGO radio-link adapters can be used for
>   data communication.

Comment: Yes, I know that I might need proprietary cables in order to flash the device to defaults.  That's why I asked "Is it possible to perform...without the Wago cable?"  I have been reading the documentation for many hours now before posting.  I'm looking for someone who has experience with Wago PLCs to help answer that question.

Comment: According to what I understand from it, if you have no access to the device through the network, you need to connect via the proprietary cable in order to access the application which does this. I don't think you are going to be able to do this any other way. Contact Wagner for clarification, or just order the necessary cable(s).